# To fill up asp.net membership

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, membership-provider

I believe I want to do a update query.

I've found a tutorial that introduces me to ASP.Net membership where I can use an Access provider to fill my database needs.  However, I have an existing Access database of customers, but I do not know how to copy this existing database into the new ASPNetDB.mdb.  It's identical to the SQL provider as far as I know.

Every table is related to each other so I cannot enter new records.  I've wanted to append the UserName column, the passwords, email's, and a new field to the new ASPNetDB.mdb.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

So instead of having to copy records from one database to another database why don't you just create a custom membership provider and use the same existing database.

Basically you create a class that inherits from the MembershipProvider class and you implement all the methods from the MembershipProvider class. I.E. ChangePassword, CreateUser, DeleteUser, etc... In your implementation you write custom code to access the tables that already exist.

This way you can keep your current database and still use ASP.NET membership.

Here is an MSDN article with a sample implementation. 
[Sample Membership Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I will try this.  I'd really like to use the existing database, but I'm not confident in my experience to mess with memberships.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, if the table structures ARE the same, then why not just make a copy of the original database and re-name to the same as your ASPNetDB.mdb.

If you're looking to import older data, then again simple open ASPNetDB.mdb with Access and import the data + tables from the older database. Access can and WILL import the tables and WILL ALSO BRING IN related data tables. This will create new local tables, but then again you stating they are the same. (so delete the existing tables in ASPNetDB and import the other ones).

You can ALSO import the table data into existing tables if they are empty. So assuming empty tables, then a compact + repair will re-set auto numbers, and then you can link to the older database and use append quires. I would only do this if a few tables.  You have to import the "parent" tables first if referential integrity is enforced as it makes little sense to add child records first!

However I fail to see why not just making a whole copy of the older existing database and re-naming it as ASPNetDB would not work if your claim of the tables being the same in both.

Comment: The existing Access database is very different from the one the Access Provider tutorial had provided.  The one from the Access Provider is identical to the Sql Provider.

Comment: You do not make it clear if you wanting to pull in the mdb  provider tables into the existing application and thus the result WILL be the same structures. Or do you want to use existing tables in the existing Access database? I mean either you pull in the provider tables into the existing app and THEN simply fill up these tables by appending data from existing tables. You still have to assign each user a role etc.